# Laravel 5: use homestead in production

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

It is good to use homestead in development.
But is it also good to use homestead in production?
If yes, should I run virtual box always?
If I host my app to clouding service, ex: AWS, how can homestead work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a script on [Laravel's Github repo](https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh) that tells you everything Homestead installs.

As far as using it in production, especially in AWS where you can easily choose another Linux box more suitable as a web server, I would seriously advise against it.

Comment: Hi, Omar. You mean not to use homestead in production?

Comment: *another Linux box more suitable as a web server* What exactly are you basing that on? Can you point to anything about the setup Homestead installs that makes it less "suitable" than any other setup?

Comment: Homestead is great but running laravel app into normal linux servers like ubuntu or centOs seems okay to me and no problem occured.